# Are onload event handlers automatically released after execution?

Tags: javascript, html

Is the onload event of something like an image released after it is executed when it's anonymous?

Like when you do this

```
var tempImg = new Image()
tempImg.onload = function () {
   alert("loaded");
}
tempImg.src = "https://images.google.ca/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png";
```

or this

```
<img id='img' />
<script>    
    var tempImg = document.getElementById("img")
    tempImg.onload = function () {
       alert("loaded");
    }
    tempImg.src = "https://images.google.ca/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png";
</script>
```

Do you have to clear it in some way to prevent the event from firing again if the image is changed somewhere else? If so, what's the correct way? Just set to undefined? Can you clear it inside itself?

Comment: I have no clue what you are asking. Are you asking if you need to remove the event listener after it is called?

Comment: Yeah, when I tried to google it, I only find ways to remove properly named listeners

Comment: @TrevorD tempImg.onload=null;

Comment: @Jonasw `= null;`?

Comment: @Jonas w Can that be done inside the function itself?

Comment: @TrevorD yes, shure

Comment: `tempImg.onload = null` is slightly more correct, since `onload` defaults to `null` for a brand-new `Image`

Comment: @TrevorD not only it can, it is very convenient: `this.onload = null;`

Comment: `tempImg.onload = function () { tempImg.onload = null; ...` or `this.onload=null`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you assign the event listener using the `onload` property, then **no, it is not automatically released**. It can fire again in certain cases like the image source being modified. You can clear it by setting it to `undefined` or `null`, or `delete`ing the property. This can be done inside the event handling function itself:

```
image.onload = function(event) {
  delete image.onload;
  /* do something */
};
```

If you are using `addEventListener()` to handle the event instead, you will need to use `removeEventListener()`. We can add an internal name to the function so we can reference it:

```
image.addEventListener('load', function myLoadHandler(event) {
  image.removeEventListener(myLoadHandler);
  /* do something */
});
```

However, in newer browsers there is a better option than either of these. You can define an event listener that will automatically remove itself by using the new `once` option:

```
image.addEventListener('load', function(event) {
  /* do something */
}, { once: true });
```

Comment: Option 3 seems very appealing.  Thanks!

Comment: Note that `delete img.onload` does not work because onload is a getter/setter. You need to use `img.onload = null`.